# how to detect numers with GetAsyncKeyState in Visual Basic 2010?

Tags: numbers, detect, basic

I'm logging key presses and  I would like to know what are number buttons called. This is an example done with the letter "A".

```
key1 = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.A)
If Key1 = True Then
    RichTextBox1.SelectedText = "A"
End If
```

How do I get this to work with numbers? Is there an another way to do this? If so, please let me know!

Thank you in forehand! :)

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) it should be Keys.D0 to Keys.D9

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is how I use it, and it works great. First, declare the 'GeyAsyncKeyState' in the class:

```
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Integer) As Short
```

Then, to get number 1:

```
If (GetAsyncKeyState(49)) Then
        'Do something with 1
End If
```

To get keypad number 1:

```
If (GetAsyncKeyState(97)) Then
        'Do something with keypad number 1
End If
```

And now you wonder, where do you get these numbers from? Here you can see which numbers is which key: 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html
Scroll down a little bit and you can see all number to key translation. The numbers you are going to use is the 'Keycode' numbers.

And if you don't want to remember all these numbers, you can create integers which store these numbers, eg.:

```
Dim Key_1 As Integer = 49
```

Comment: @user3364046 What about it?